# unaccounted space in list item after transform rotate

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, transform

I've got a transform in a list and there appears to be space after the effect. As the item is inline, I presume this to be the reason.

That said, I'm looking for a solution - to return the word back to HYBRID without spaces.

**visual**
[image: visual of spacing error]
**css**

```
.hybrid {
    display:inline-block;
    transform:rotate(180deg);
}    

.sidebar-nav li {
  line-height: 40px;
  text-indent: 20px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
  color: #999999;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

**html**

```
<li>
    <a href="#overview">Overview of H<span class="hybrid">Y</span>BRID</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `span` is inheriting a text-indent from `.sidebar-nav li` (line 63 of stylish-portfolio.css). Fix it with:

CSS

```
.hybrid {   
    text-indent: 0;
}
```